# Pyinstaller error 'Failed to determine version'

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller, invoice, auto-py-to-exe

from the error 'Unhandled exception in script' I can see that it somehow doesn't recognise module Mindee
in my code it's imported as
'from mindee import Client, documents'

I tried --hidden import, but nothing seems to work it's always the same error
importing only mindee doesn't work too

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with `pikepdf`. The solution was to add `--copy-metadata pikepdf` to the pyinstaller args like so:

```
pyinstaller --copy-metadata pikepdf main.py
```

If you have a `.spec` file you can add the following:

```
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import copy_metadata

datas = []
datas += copy_metadata('pikepdf')

# ...

a = Analysis(
    # ...,
    datas=datas,
    # ...,
)

# ...
```

I hope this helps someone as this question is older.

Answer (score 0):

Something similar happened to me. It seems to look for a version file inside path/main/version folder that doesn't exists (and it doesn't creates either)

Comment: This should be a comment instead